# Building GLFW for codeblocks

Tags: codeblocks, glfw

I'm trying to build GLFW from source for Code Blocks. I used Cmake and it made a directory and I opened the Code blocks project file and clicked the gear to build. The only thing new in src is libglfw3.a and I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, are you following a tutorial?

Comment: Yes but its done in visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're following the LearnOpenGL tutorial. Actually, i tried to do the same as he recommended, but i ended up following this tutorial which is way more simple to apply https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WrSGMuU964&t=0s . It's using the pre-compiled binaries folder, that's why it is not using Cmake. To make it short (under windows), you only need to copy/paste the include and lib-mingw folders in your project folder. Then open your project with Code::Blocks and go in Project/Build options... . In Search directories under the compiler tab, you need to add the include directory you just copy/pasted and under the linker tab, you do the same thing with the lib-mingw dir. Now in the linker settings tab (next to search directories) you need to add glw3, gdi32, and opengl32, and that's all it should be working now :) I only wrote the tutorial in case one day it disappears from youtube :p

Answer (score 0):

This was posted a while ago but I think I built the static GLFW library for linux with WSL CMake instead of Windows CMake.